# ReactJS: converting html files into React components

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs, reactjs-flux

Lets say I have **Test1.html,Test2.html, Test3.html ...etc** files having different form data. I want to generate reactJS components like **Test1.js, Test2.js Test3.js** components with complete information.

we have idea like one common reactjs plugin to take any html file as input and automatically converts react components. As a developer no need to write separate code for converting their own component from html file. just i want to make it plugin

just upload the html file as input and generate the reactjs component with complete data.

make it **.html** files are input and
expected output is react component.

Please let me know any one how to do this that would be great????

Comment: This may be possible in the completely trivial case of "dumb" presentational components consisting only of HTML elements but anything more than that will be very difficult. It sounds like you're asking for something magic here.

Comment: let me give clarity onthis   var htmlInput = '<div><h1>Title</h1><p>A paragraph</p></div>';//upload html file                                                   var SampleOneComponent = React.createClass({

  render: function() {
    return (
     htmlInput;
    );
  }
});

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea. I don't know if you need to perform some operations with state in your react components or just need the html. If you only need to have html in render(), you can do something like that:

```
componentWillMount() {
    // get your data from html
    ...
    this.data = your_data;
}

render() {
    return (
        <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.data}}></div>
    );
}
```

But again, it's not recommended !

Comment: yes phan you said right, but i want to make common plugin, everyone want to reuse it for converingt their own component. reactjs is purely component based. so here making html files into components.

Comment: You can base on https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-to-react-components. Give it a try.

Comment: Can you please provide me download link for above code.

Comment: If you use npm: npm install html-to-react-components. Or this is the github link: https://github.com/roman01la/html-to-react-components